# i cant find a solution for this plot

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, matlab-figure

I am trying to find this plot using `mathematica` [matlab version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02cRt.png)

Here's the [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHrgx.png)
and here's:

- the [mathematica code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCsXB.png)
- the [mathematica result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwnPj.png)

I tried but I can't identify the problem nor find a solution.

Comment: Mathematica shows me me a warning/error message `Exp[-7.8835*10^12] is too small to represent...` If I insert `/10^12` inside both of your `Exp[]` then I believe that scales up the vertical axis of your plot and the error message goes away and I see a plot. Try that and see if you get the same.

Comment: Could you please post code as text, not image? To help you, someone has to try the code in Mathematica, but that's a lot to type... Also, consider asking questions about Mathematica to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `w=0.08*10^-3;l=632.8*10^-9;s=10*10^-3;fx=20*10^6;fy=20*10^6;v=1500;
Plot3D[Sum[BesselJ[1.5,p]^2*Exp[-2*((Pi*w)/(l*s))^2*(x-p*((l*s*fx)/v))^2/10^12],{p,-50,50}]*
Sum[BesselJ[1.5,q]^2*Exp[-2*((Pi*w)/(l*s))^2*(y-q*((l*s*fy)/v))^2/10^12],{q,-50,50}],
{x,-50,50},{y,-50,50},PlotRange->All]`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying this out, here is the code (thanks to @Bill):

```
w = 0.08*10^-3; 
l = 632.8*10^-9; 
s = 10*10^-3; 
fx = 20*10^6; 
fy = 20*10^6; v = 1500;

Plot3D[
 Sum[
   BesselJ[1.5, p]^2*
    Exp[-2*((Pi*w)/(l*s))^2*(x - p*((l*s*fx)/v))^2], {p, -50, 
    50}
   ]*Sum[
   BesselJ[1.5, q]^2*
    Exp[-2*((Pi*w)/(l*s))^2*(y - q*((l*s*fy)/v))^2], {q, -50, 
    50}
   ],
 {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50},
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "BesselJ[1.5,x]"}, 
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 ]
```

Running this results in the error:

```
General::munfl: Exp[-7.88544*10^12] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-7.88547*10^12] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: Exp[-7.88549*10^12] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Multiplying by a factor of `10^-11` inside both exponential functions, i.e., `Exp[-2*((Pi*w)/(l*s))^2*(x - p*((l*s*fx)/v))^2*10^-12]` and `Exp[-2*((Pi*w)/(l*s))^2*(y - q*((l*s*fy)/v))^2*10^-12]` and changing the range to `{x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}` yields the following plot:
[image]

It's not exactly the same as the MatLab plot but it's closer!